# gdb command file scripting: wait for breakpoint supported?

Tags: scripting, gdb

Im debugging quite a complex program with lots of queues, each having a relatively short timeout period set.
I cannot debug reliable in gdb's 'manual' command line mode, because timeouts are triggered when I type commands to slowly.

I don't like the idea of extending all the queue's timeouts, as this would make things really messy. (This sounds like the design itself is arguable, I know...)

I'd really like to use the gdb 'scripting' feature, but I haven't found a good tutorial for this.

Could anyone tell me if this is possible in a gdb "command file" script:

- init some things (easy)
- set a breakpoint
- run programm
- have the next command in script executed once the breakpoint is hit

So basically my question is: can I wait for a breakpoint inside a gdb command file script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question: I had success using hooks. My command file looks like this:

```
[initialization code]

define hook-stop
[commands to be executed at breakpoint]
end

set breakpoint pending on
b my_breakpoint_function
r
```